# Clingo: operation undefined

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

Adding the following rule to my code results in an error message (`info: operation undefined (Max-Min)`):

```
rank_difference(Room, Deck, Diff) :-
    played(Room, Deck),
    Min = #min {Rank: seat(Player, Room, Deck), rank(Player, Rank)},
    Max = #max {Rank: seat(Player, Room, Deck), rank(Player, Rank)},
    Diff = Max - Min.
```

`played(Room, Deck)` implies that there exists at least one `seat(Player, Room, Deck)` predicate (in fact that there exist exactly 3 or 4) while `rank(Player, Rank)` exists for each player so this isn't supposed to be an empty set issue.

**Update - Runnable example (without any of the constraints):**

```
#const nRounds = 4.
#const nPlayers = 13.
#const nRooms = 4.
#const nDecks = 10.

player(1..nPlayers).
room(1..nRooms).
deck(1..nDecks).
writer(1,1;2,2;3,3;4,4).
rank(Player, Player) :- player(Player).

nRounds { round(Player, 1..nDecks) } nRounds :- player(Player).
{ played(Room, Deck) } :- room(Room), deck(Deck).
3 { seat(Player, Room, Deck) : round(Player, Deck) } 4 :- played(Room, Deck).

rank_difference(Room, Deck, Diff) :-
    played(Room, Deck),
    Min = #min {Rank: seat(Player, Room, Deck), rank(Player, Rank)},
    Max = #max {Rank: seat(Player, Room, Deck), rank(Player, Rank)},
    Diff = Max - Min.
```

Comment: Your encoding looks correct, can you create a sample instance where I can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 2):

The grounder can not infer that the set inside your min/max aggregate isn't actually empty. Therefore valid solutions (at least during grounding) are also `#sup` for `#min` and `#inf` for `#max`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum
Doing arithmetic with these values is undefined.
You have to explicitly bound the result of the operation so in this case:

```
rank_difference(Room, Deck, Diff) :-
    played(Room, Deck),
    Min = #min {Rank: seat(Player, Room, Deck), rank(Player, Rank)},
    Max = #max {Rank: seat(Player, Room, Deck), rank(Player, Rank)},
    rank(_, Min), rank(_, Max),
    Diff = Max - Min.
```